# lua:1: unexpected symbol near 'ï'

Tags: c#, lua

More specifically the full error is

> ../../Scripts/LuaTest.lua:1: unexpected symbol near 'ï'

I have checked the `LuaTest.lua` file with different editors to include Notepad++ and can not find any extra/hidden characters. I'm at a loss to what could be causing this.

Side note, I'm following this guide: [Godpatterns: Scripting with Lua in C#](http://www.godpatterns.com/2006/05/scripting-with-lua-in-c.html)

Here is the main code block:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Lua lua = new Lua();
        Program program = new Program();

        // register our C# functions
        lua.RegisterFunction("DanSays", program, program.GetType().GetMethod("DanSays"));
        lua.RegisterFunction("ThorSays", program, program.GetType().GetMethod("ThorSays"));

        lua.DoFile("../../Scripts/LuaTest.lua");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void DanSays(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dan Says > " + s);
    }
    public void ThorSays(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thor says > " + s);
    }

}
```

Additionally, here is `LuaTest.lua`

```lua
DanSays("Hey, Thor!");
ThorSays("Hi Dan! You know Thursdays . . . ");
DanSays("*sigh* yeah, Thor, I know Thursdays.");
ThorSays("Named after me you know!");
DanSays("Yeah, I know.");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely caused by a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that is placed at the start of Unicode text files by some text editors. The bytes of the BOM include 0xEF, which is the [ISO 8859-1 character code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) for ï (latin lowercase i with umlaut).

So your guess is correct, there *are* hidden characters in there. Configure your text editor to **not** use a BOM when writing text files.

Comment: Thanks Greg, learn something new everyday. Here is a link on BOM in Visual Studio: [utf-8 without BOM in visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom-in-visual-studio-2010)