# Byte Order Mark (BOM) and PHP files

Tags: prestashop, byte-order-mark

I am using PrestaShop (1.5.2) for my website. Some time ago, an error creeped into the entire website,  Line 1, Column 1: character "" not allowed in prolog (according to the W3C Validator). This results in a complete messy rendering in IE, and needs to be fixed ASAP.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom-in-visual-studio-2010) which offers a solution to the problem, except for one thing. Which file should I resave with "UTF-8 without signature" settings? I tried the .htaccess, php.ini, index.php without any luck. Is it specific to a file, or could it be some text in the database?

I uploaded a test .html file, and a test .php file which worked without any problem. 
What is the common factor? If it is related to the database, how can it influence the entire page output?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I already found the solution. Apparently this char (ó) in the translation file caused it all... Anyway problem solved