# Handlebars or backbone insert empty string into html

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to handlebars and backbone and I'm currently trying to have precompiled handlebar templates on my web page.
However what happens is that handlebars or backbone, I don't know which, adds an empty string into the DOM. I don't know why. This same thing does not happen when I compile the templates in a backbone view.

What is even stranger to me is that I have one precompiled handlebar template to which this doesn't happen...

Here is a picture of the html when precompiled:

[image]

Here is a picture when compiling within a backbone view:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I've tried to simplify the precompiled template file by compiling only the simplest template that doesn't accept any data and looking into the file for the problem... I've changed the return string, but it didn't fix the issue, so I'm thinking the problem has to be somewhere within backbone...

The simple template:

```
<div id="channelsContainer"></div>
<div>
    <div id="postsContainer"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="contentContainer"></div>
        <div id="detailsContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Returning the precompiled template from the template function in a backbone view:

```
template:   function(data)
    {
        return Handlebars.templates['shell.html'];
    }
```

Returning the template while compiling in the view:

```
template:   function(data)
        {
            var handlebarTemplate = Handlebars.compile('<div id="channelsContainer"></div> \
<div> \
    <div id="postsContainer"></div> \
    <div> \
        <div id="contentContainer"></div> \
        <div id="detailsContainer"></div> \
    </div> \
</div>');

            return handlebarTemplate;
        }
```

In the same backbone view, in the initialize method:

```
this.$el.empty().html(this.template());
```

Any help with figuring out what is happening is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the answer to the problem... He just saved the file with UTF-8 without BOM encoding...
Resource:
[UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom)

It seems that Visual Studio saves the files with an inappropriate encoding...

Thank you both for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but I had a similar problem with one of my templates. In my case, it was that inline templates are strings parsed into DOM nodes, not XML parsed into DOM nodes. As a result any errant whitespace was being converted into TEXT elements after the parse, which were finding their way into the DOM when the template was called.

Comment: I've tried eliminating all whitespaces and new lines... the problem is still there... is there a way I can parse a string to XML or DOM node? Do you think that would solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I thought I would mention it just in case, as that turned out to be my problem and so I thought it might be yours as well.