# Android Studio:error: illegal character: '\u2028'

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying to do a JSONObject request:

```
final String URL = "https://some/url";

// Post params to be sent to the server
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("param1", param1);
 params.put("param2", param2);
 params.put("param3", param3);     
params.put("param4", param4);


JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", "läuft");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
    }
});

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
NetworkController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

I cannot compile the project because I get a syntax error for the params:

> Error:(144, 9) error: illegal character: '\u2028'

How can I fix that?

Comment: Remove that character?

Comment: I have looked the character up: u2028 means line separator. I do not have a line separator in my params

Comment: Delete that character at that position and type it again.

Comment: First, is this a compile-time error or a runtime error?

Comment: it is a compile error

Comment: Log is saying error on 144 line. Which line number is 144

Comment: it is the line with param2. it looks originally:  params.put("os", os); I did a string request with exactly the same params before and I got no compile error before

Comment: Lock this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46703815/1770868

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, just deleting all the characters and rewriting them again helped. So crazy..

Answer (score 41):

It's the new line character, if you go to each of the lines that are causing the error and delete the 'invisible' last character then the errors will resolve

Go to end of the line that is causing the error and hit backspace once, for each of the lines that have the illegal character error.

Comment: This worked. I had to hit backspace a couple of times on some of the lines though.

Comment: Crazy Android Studio, end of the java line pressing delete works fine but for some lines, you have to move your cursor to starting of the line and move again to end of the line and then press delete to remove /u2028 character error.. Irritated. but what's the reason for this?

Answer (score 15):

If you are mac user then you can

Copy and paste text in TextWrangler
View -> Text  Display -> Show Invisibles

It will show you symbol like "|". Delete this and you are good to go.

Answer (score 11):

Best is to use replace feature from Android Studio, put an empty string in *"Replace with"*:

[image: Android studio replace]

Comment: Make sure you have Regex checked and this works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Cut and paste the code into a text editor to convert it to simple text. Then remove all extra spaces.  After that, use Android Studio's *Reformat code* feature to make it nice again.

For me, only deleting the spaces in Android Studio did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue but in my case the number of errors were pretty large(95 or so). The only sane thing to do was to replace these characters with an empty character. This short Python script would do that and print out the new contents for your file. Run it with the correct path to your file. Cheers.

```
with open(‘filename.java’, ‘r’) as file:
    data=(file.read().decode(“utf-8”)).replace(u’\u2028', ‘’).encode(“utf-8”)
    print data
```