# Android studio : error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Tags: android, windows, encoding, build

first, my project is building and working correctly from android studio under macOS natively (not a VM). 
My problem is on a windows machine (still not a VM) where everything build correctly but still I have some encoding errors.(12 errors)

`error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8`
`error: illegal character: '\ufffd'`

So I try this : 
[Android Studio : unmappable character for encoding UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677855/android-studio-unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8)

Now I only have 4 errors which are like this one:
`error: illegal character: '\ufffd'`
`public static final int XXXX_view_account_account_js_cities_gen�ve = 0x7f0a0953;`

I tried :
1. [Android Studio:error: illegal character: '\u2028'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578142/android-studioerror-illegal-character-u2028) => Try to delete and rewrite it
2. I tried also ISO-8859-1 encoding

Here is my gradle build and settings build :

```
 android {  
     compileSdkVersion 25   
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"   
     compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
```

and
[SETTINGS IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhhgJ.png)

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: `2.^ Grey areas indicate non-assigned code points`

Comment: Yes I am aware of that I do not understand why it does not work on windows but on Mac regardless of what I have tried so far.

Comment: I think is because your android studio on mac can be setting to write file with other encoding if you want see you see it at bottom right of android studio windows  and change it.