# Error: Found byte-order-mark in the middle of a file [ByteOrderMark]

Tags: android, android-build

When I am trying to generate apk build for release that time I am getting this error. How to fix it? Please help!

[image]

Comment: See this Answer. it solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669026/5282127

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete all the spaces in front of the string[image]