# Azure WebJobs ConsoleApp error

Tags: azure-webjobs

I experimented with WebJobs over the weekend, and my console app worked fine - until today. It started failing with this error message on the log page:

```
[03/26/2014 19:21:30 > 8fa263: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: SYS INFO] Run script 'IncidentPoll.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: ERR ] 'IncidentPoll.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: ERR ] operable program or batch file.
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[03/26/2014 19:21:31 > 8fa263: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

I didn't change anything this morning. So I'm wondering if there's a policy change that occurred since last weekend?

**EDIT:** This webjob, is under the Websites Free tier. It was scheduled to fire every 10 minutes. Could it be because they (Microsoft) found this as a loophole? They also have a (dedicated) Scheduler Service (preview), in which under the Free tier, the maximum frequency that you can run is once per hour.

Comment: The error says the file (`IncidentPoll.exe`) doesn't exist but since it should, can you verify whether it's in the following directories: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\{jobname}` and `%temp%\jobs\triggered\{jobname}\{somerandomname}`, you can use DebugConsole tool on your scm site (https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net) more information on that in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that will soon be fixed, for now as a workaround move `IncidentPoll.exe` to be in the root of your WebJobs directory (if you're using a zip to upload your WebJob, make sure the zip has this binary at the root).

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. But I didn't know if this was the fix. Thanks . Previously, I zipped the whole "Release" folder. You confirmed it.

Comment: @Amit - I just got the same error when publishing a console app from VS 2013 (by right-clicking on the project and selecting "Publish as Azure Webjob").  Is there a fix I can find?  Per this screenshot I took my exe is in the webjob's root.  http://imgur.com/DoG6PN6

Comment: @Amit - UPDATE: The problem was the spaces in the assembly name.  Apparently Azure doesn't like that.

Comment: @Matt interesting, can you open an issue on http://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues ?

Answer (score 2):

I was met with a very similar issue when running the executable from `run.cmd`. So I fired up the [Kudu debug console](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/videos/super-secret-kudu-debug-console-for-azure-web-sites/) and manually invoked `run.cmd`. The result was the following:

> 'ï»¿Foo.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

It was pretty clear now that the culprit was that strange `ï»¿` prefix. A quick web search turned up [UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom) which demystified the issue - Visual Studio was adding a UTF BOM header that was confusing the Kudu (Azure) shell.

Fortunately the thread also contained a simple fix. In Visual Studio: *File* -> *Advanced Save Options* -> *Encoding* -> *Unicode (UTF-8 **without signature**)*.