# Fix Enconding with BOM in file ... Working on MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, utf-8, notepad++

I am working on an MVC site with Visual Studio 2012.

When I validate the site in W3C I get a Warning:

```
Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File.

The Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM) in UTF-8 encoded files is known to cause problems for some text editors and older browsers. You may want to consider avoiding its use until it is better supported.
```

I used Notepad ++ to change the enconding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without BOM.

In this case some characters (á, ç, à, ...) in the webpage are displayed in a strange way ...

How can I fix this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

I'd typically not worry too much about this warning.

But if you care you can add a meta tag to your files and also do the conversion in visual studio itself.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
```

Here is an so thread on how to save without BOM in visual studio:
[UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom)