# Displaying Unicode in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unicode, utf-8

I've tried almost anything to display Unicode in Visual Studio 2013, C++.

Starting with:

```
cmd /K chcp 65001
```

to changing the 'Character Set' in visual studio.

I'll be glad to get some help, of what I should do.

Comment: UTF-8 is not supported in the console, [you can however use UTF-16](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx)

Comment: @Mgetz and how can I do it?

Comment: In fact, UTF-8 is supported in the console, surprizingly. You need some trickery for that. See http://utf8everywhere.org. If you do not find, ask me again.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app/9051543#9051543.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run UTF-8, you need a Byte Order Mark (BOM) sometimes called a **signature.**

[Per the MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx)

> Unicode characters are now supported in identifiers, macros, string and character literals, and in comments. Universal character names are also now supported.
>
> Unicode can be input into a source code file in the following encodings:
>
> - UTF-16 little endian with or without byte order mark (BOM)
> - UTF-16 big endian with or without BOM
> - UTF-8 with BOM

For the love of all things decent, do NOT use "UTF-8 with BOM!"

You can [do what was done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom) and simply save the file you need by going to "Advanced Save Options" and selection "UTF-8 without BOM" (signature). This only works on a file by file basis, but there is a discussion about installing something called [File Fix Encoding](http://vlasovstudio.com/fix-file-encoding/), which will take off the BOM on ALL files.

In other words -- you can only display UTF-8 on a file-by-file basis unless you install File Fix Encoding.

Hope this helps.