# Why Chrome shows \ufeff symbol and gray lines in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

1. When I open my TypeScript in Chrome debugger I see strange red dot at the first line. I believe it corresponds to unrendered symbol \ufeff (as popover says). There is no such symbol in the TS file when I open it in editor (e. g., Notepad++ with "show all symbols"). Where does this symbol come from?
2. This file also contains some lines colored in gray. It seems that I cannot insert breakpoint to that lines (e. g., line #17 on the picture). How can I get rid of it?

[image: TS or JS troubles in Chrome]

In FireFox all this issues are not presented. I have no strange symbol at the beginning of the file and I can insert breakpoint to lines which were grayed out in Chrome.

**Update**. I have found that \ufeff corresponds to [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is likely generated by [--emitBOM](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) option of the TypeScript compiler. Now can someone explain how can I remove this option? I can't find any reference to "tsc" in my project file when I open it in a text editor as well as I can't find any proper options in Visual Studio GUI (Web Express).

**Update 2**. I have learnt from [this discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1yfnto/what_is_this_red_bulletdot_in_my_json_response_in/) that with help of \ufeff = BOM Chrome can indicate a developer that there is something wrong in the code. But the BOM appears even when I comment out all code in my file.

Comment: You might want to search up what U+FEFF is used for, which might provide some insight into why this happens.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks for the clue. I have updated the question. However I am still confused that this symbol (U+FEFF = BOM) is not presented in the file when I view it with text editor.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes, I have looked at this page but didn't find anything connected with my problem. Do you mean some concrete section on this page?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy update to your link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Chrome somehow doesn't like UTF-8 with BOM. And this is exactly an encoding which my instance of Visual Studio did save file in. I have switched the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM and the described problems have disappeared.

How to: [corresponding StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom). In two words: 1) select desired encoding while saving via "Save as...", *or* 2) go to File/Advanced Save Options... and select the encoding for all files (you need to add this menu item if you have no one). The encoding is called "UTF-8 without signature".

Answer (score 3):

> When I open my TypeScript in Chrome debugger I see strange red dot at the first line. I believe it corresponds to unrendered symbol \ufeff

Yes this is the BOM as other answers have already pointed out. For 2:

> This file also contains some lines colored in gray. It seems that I cannot insert breakpoint to that lines (e. g., line #17 on the picture). How can I get rid of it?

These are lines *that are not there in the sourcemap*. This is the way chrome dev tools show *unmapped to generated JS* source code. So you cannot place a breakpoint in here as the runtime doesn't know which *JS* corresponds to this *TS*.