# gulp-concat with woofmark - introduces illegal token into output

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, byte-order-mark, gulp-concat

My website project has a few JavaScript library dependencies, and I am using the `gulp-concat` plugin in my `gulpfile.js` to bundle them as one library instead of including them separately:

```
gulp.src(['src/js/angular.min.js',
          'src/js/angular-route.min.js',
          'src/js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
          'src/js/domador.min.js',
          'src/js/megamark.min.js',
          'src/js/woofmark.min.js'])
.pipe(concat('libs.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

A problem was introduced once I added the `domador`, `megamark` and `woofmark` libraries.

Although these libraries work perfectly fine if referenced in the HTML separately, bundling them introduces some illegal characters into my `libs.js` which breaks Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Dev Tools shows me that there are indeed three unexpected characters in-between where `megamark.min.js` finishes and `woofmark.min.js` starts:

[image]

But! When I look at `libs.js` in Visual Studio:

[image]

There seems to be some kind of 'hidden' characters in the mix which become 'unhidden' to Chrome and kill the script. I don't understand why they are there or why none of things I've tried to remedy it are working...

What I have tried:

- Bundle everything except `woofmark.min.js` and include that separately. Yes, this works, but I want to bundle them all (and I want to understand what is happening)
- Re-saved the files in Notepad as UTF-8 encoding. No effect.
- Backspaced from half-way through the first keyword in `woofmark.min.js`, many more times than necessary, then re-typed the necessary characters. No effect.
- Similar effort for the last few characters of `megamark.min.js`. No effect.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What server used for script delivery to browser? What default charset on it? I see, that `shchcy: "щ"` also incorrect.

Comment: Server should to response with `content-type:application/javascript; UTF-8` header for `.js` files.

Comment: This symbols - is just BOM marker. It should be correctly parsed if utf-8 used.

Comment: In this instance it would be Visual Studio 2015's IIS Express, not sure how to determine it's default charset. The crazy characters in the rest of the code are intentional, part of `woofmark`s functionality as far as I know, they don't seem to cause issue.

Comment: Anyway, one-byte charset was used on the first screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom

Comment: Thanks, your info has led me to the specific solution, I'll write it up as a detailed answer

Comment: just switch your studio to not generate signatures and delete this question, it's duplicate...

Comment: I couldn't find the answer on SO as I didn't know about BOM and was unable to find any resource that would explain why the issue only appeared when bundling - is it worth keeping as a specific issue?

Comment: I think, that you would not be able find this answer too :) Let it be..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the information provided by **vp_arth** in the comments, I found the solution.

It seems that the `woofmark.min.js` file was encoded as "UTF-8 with signature", which is another way of saying that it has the invisible BOM marker which produced the illegal characters.

When sent separately by IIS it was being converted, but when concatenated in a bundle, the marker was being retained in the middle of the file, creating the illegal token.

To fix, I re-saved the file with a different encoding in Visual Studio:

- File ->
- Save src/js/woofmark.min.js As... ->
- Save with Encoding... -> *(button drop-down)*
- Select "**Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001**" from options.

Then, after re-running the gulp task, the full bundled `lib.js` works perfectly.