# Visual studio adding white space on git merge

Tags: git, visual-studio, whitespace

How do we prevent leading whitespace being added while Visual Studio 2015 touches files when merging branches.

[Whitespace Shown in Stash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ugPt.png)

Example above is what is show in Stash during pull request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525417/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-line-endings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have VS2015, but it looks like Unicode BOM. Search for option to add it in the VS editor configuration.

[Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411486/2303202)