# Azure Linux App Service: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
ENV "GEM_HOME" "/home/gems"
ENV "BUNDLE_PATH" "/home/gems"
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /home/webapp
CMD ["/home/webapp/startup.sh"]
```

The startup.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle install
bundle exec rails server puma -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

With this Dockerfile I build an image on Docker Hub.
I choose this image in the Azure Linux App Service Website Docker Container settings. No problems here.

Via FTP I upload my Rails app (is in folder webapp, this folder contains the startup.sh file) in the / folder of the Linux App Service.
According to a comment on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-how-to-create-a-web-app the / of the App Service is mapped to /home in the container.

However my webapp won't show if I access it via the browser. In

```
/LogFiles/docker/docker_***_err.log
```

it says:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

What I am trying to achieve is that my app data and gems are outside the container image.
I tested the image successfully on my local mac with:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:3000 -v /Users/***/Desktop/ms:/home xyz/rubyimage
```

The ms folder contains the folder webapp.

Comment: I changed the last line in the Dockerfile to: CMD bundle install && bundle exec rails server puma -b 0.0.0.0 -e production. This works, however I still don't know why the .sh file can't be executed or is not found.

Comment: I commented on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258695/azure-linux-app-service-just-start-one-container.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the #!/bin/sh in the start.sh causes the trouble. Try putting #!/bin/bash there.

Source:
https://forums.docker.com/t/getting-panic-spanic-standard-init-linux-go-178-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory-red-while-running-the-docker-image/27318/4

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a windows machine, it was because of the line endings on the first line in my "entrypoint.sh" file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code, and fixed by changing the line ending from "CRLF" to "LF":

[Visual Studio Code: How to show line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525417/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-line-endings)