# Azure Linux App Service: Just start one container

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am using this Dockerfile on Azure Linux App Service:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
ENV "GEM_HOME" "/home/gems"
ENV "BUNDLE_PATH" "/home/gems"
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /home/webapp
CMD bundle install && bundle exec rails server puma -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

As you can see the gems folder is located in the home folder. The home folder is shared with the host system of the App Service. Now my problem the App Service LogFiles/docker/docker_***_out.log indicates that bundle install is called multiple times (probably from different containers). This leads to that some gems are never successfully installed.

Is there some setting which runs just one container so that my gems can be installed successfully and not interferring with each other? Or am I making wrong assumptions here? Maybe the problem isn't that there a multiple containers started?

Is there an easier way to install the gems the first time in the shared folder of the host system?

Comment: Are you scaled out to more than one instance? It's likely either that, or an AppSetting update or something else is causing the container to be restarted. Concurrent access to /home and the container being restarted are both things that are going to happen - if you intend to do some kind of one-time setup work in /home via a container CMD/ENTRYPOINT, the script you run there will need logic to make sure things are idempotent, locking etc. Another option for one-time work on your /home drive is to do it via the Kudu console or app install via Kudu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No it is just one instance, there are no AppSetting updates. Usign Kudu is a good idea, didn't try this yet. Maybe this behavior changes in the future as its a Preview.