# Neo4j + Docker - unable to create JVM

Tags: docker, neo4j, jvm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker container for a Neo4j DB. While running the db locally isn't an issue, the container is having issues starting the JVM. Looking through the neo4j:3.2.2 image I'm building my own Dockerfile from I can't see us using different versions of the JRE. The issue seems to stem from they neo4j.conf, where It crashes on unrecognized VM option flags, such as `UseG1GC` and `OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

The Dockerfile is fairly short

```
FROM neo4j:3.2.2
ADD ./neo4j.conf /var/lib/neo4j/conf/.
ADD ./data/. /var/lib/neo4j/import
ADD ./scripts/. .
```

I've also got a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
 services:
  neo4j:
    image: eu.gcr.io/tine-matsans-v2/neo4j:develop
    container_name: neo4j
    build:
      context: ./neo4j/.
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      - NEO4J_USERNAME=neo4j
      - NEO4J_PASSWORD=litago
```

I'm on a Windows 10 machine, but the image builds a unix container. My colleague has no issues whatsoever with running the container, using the same configs, though he's using a Mac. That should not be relevant as the issue is within the container.

```
neo4j            | Active database: graph.db
neo4j            | Directories in use:
neo4j            |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j            |   config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf     
neo4j            |   logs:         /var/lib/neo4j/logs
neo4j            |   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
neo4j            |   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
neo4j            |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j            |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j            |   run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
neo4j            | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j            | Unrecognized VM option 'UseG1GC
neo4j            | Did you mean '(+/-)UseG1GC'?
neo4j            | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
neo4j            | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Has anyone run into similar issues? I've searched through several stack overflow posts as well as tried to read up on how the JVM and Containers work, but I can't find any solid information to help me sort this out.

Comment: Nopes, I tried it just now and there were no issues. Probably there is something wrong in your conf file.

Comment: The weird part is, me and my colleague are using the same conf file.

Comment: Did you check EOL and hidden characters (break lines ...)? Because I suppose "Unrecognized VM option" error message is usually enclosed in `'`. And second `'` is missing

Comment: I just ran into the same issue.  If there is a known solution I would also appreciate hearing about it.  I'm running on Windows 10 as well using the neo4j:3.2.2 image which was working yesterday.  The was a recent update that was pushed to my machine but not sure what that included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this same issue.  Turned out to be a the line endings on the neo4j.conf file.  I used the VS code to switch the line endings to 'LF' and ran docker-compose up and everything worked out.  Hope this helps.

[Visual Studio Code: How to show line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525417/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-line-endings)

Answer (score 1):

Had to stop the docker-machine, go to the conf file, using notepadd++ convert file to UTF8 even if it's already utf8, edit eof to unix, save, docker-machine start, docker-compose up yey works

Comment: Mad. From the "Edit" menu, select "EOL Conversion" -> "UNIX (LF)" -> Save

Answer (score 1):

I easily solved this issue with Sublime. You can check your current line ending at menu -> view -> line endings. Just turn it into Unix and save.

I hope this helps others.