# Git commit removes line breaks

Tags: git, line-endings

Hi I've a problem commiting a file in VSCode (1.30.1) using git source control (2.19.1.windows.1). The commit changes a file, I did not change and want not to be changed. The setup is the following: I am on Windows 10, having git configured with "checkout windows style, commit unix style" `git config --global core.autocrlf true`. But when I commit the following happens.

It is a .json file with the following key:

```
{
  "description":
    "xxxxxxx"
},
```

but my commit turns this line into

```
{
  "description": "xxxxxxx"
},
```

Tested `core.autocrlf input` and `false`. But that does not fix that issue. Didn't face that behaviour before. Any other suggestions or ideas? Thanks and cheers.

---

**Update**: Another example

Creating a test.json file containing

```
{
  "test1": {},
  "test2": {}
}
```

works perfectly, but adding a new line like

```
{
  "test1": {
  },
  "test2": {}
}
```

will look like the first one after commiting. It seems like a styling issue in some way, not depending on editor or system, because other repos are working as expected.

Comment: Where did you see the second version of your JSON?  Did you view it on the repo (e.g. on GitHub or Bitbucket) _after_ you committed it?

Comment: Both locally and on github

Comment: Can you post your git configuration (or at least whatever isn't sensitive) with `git config -l`?

Comment: What linebreak style is your editor set to? On Windows you have `\r\n`, on UNIX just `\n`. Perhaps the line break vanishes because your editor just sets the `\n` and git expects the `\r` as well?

Comment: How can I get that info? As I said its windows 10, latest VSCode and "checkout windows, commit unix"-style, but tested the other styles as well.

Comment: what is the difference of the files when openning them in a hex-editor? (I doubt that line break handling is the issue since the braces are sill on their own  lines.)

Comment: Not allowed to install additional editors on my machine besides VSCode and VS.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle In an online hex editor the original file contains `0D 0A 20 20 ...`. When I create a new line manually on my machine its only `0A 20 20 ...`, but both commits are removing the line-breaks, ending in a single `20` between `"description":` and `"xx..."`.

Comment: what about the linebreaks before and after the braces?

Comment: If I add a `"test": {<line break>}` the line-break will be removed after the commit.

Comment: Could it be a VSC configuration issue, what line ending is VSC detecting/using for this file? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525417/visual-studio-code-how-to-show-line-endings)

Comment: It was `CRLF`. But using `LF` adding a new line, the line-break will be removed. Is git aware of `$schema`s? It is contains a `$schema` property containing "http://json-schema.org/schema".

Comment: Removing it doesn't work either. But it behaves like a formatting thing. E.g. `"test": {},<line-break>"test2": {}` works perfectly.

Comment: I'd bet your editor imposes auto formatting

Comment: Forget about your git configuration for a minute, what does your VS Code configuration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) library in combination with a `precommit` hook in **package.json**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

It formats the code due to given linting rules before commiting. If you like to get more details, have a look at the `@ngrx/platform` [library](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) which is using it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Or you can try with

`.gitattributes` file. You can use it as a template for your repositories:

```
# Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto
```