# JavaScript slice() working differently locally than online using Github site

Tags: javascript, github, localhost, slice

I'm parsing text file using Javascript. On the lines I have `slice()` function, my code appear to behave differently on local host and online

for example

```
if(connection == 'local') {
     value = d.substring(split2, split3).substr(1).slice(0, -1);
}
else if(connection == 'online') {
     value = d.substring(split2, split3).substr(1);
}
```

However this piece of code solve it but I cannot understand the behavior, it seems like when I use my code online that are extra hidden characters on the text file or something

Comment: `\r\n` vs `\n` probably... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532890/2159528)

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more context.  How is `connection` determined?  What exactly are the sources of `d`?  How are you running your code both locally and online?  The issue is not in the code you've currently got in the question.

Comment: what does github have to do with your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
value = d.substring(split2, split3).substr(1).trim();
```

`trim()` should remove any spaces and Escape Sequences.

Comment: some Escape sequences are hidden when you tries to debug your app, for example if you have `"\rfoo"` it will be shown as `"foo"` but actually it's not.

Comment: yes I think its about \r but whats the difference between localhost and online server?