# flask serving byte-order-mark ï»¿

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, flask

I am trying to use Flask and for some reason it is rendering with a byte-order mark that's a quirk of something using UTF8 (the mark is **ï»¿** in particular for people googling the same issue).

I do not know how to get rid of it or if it is a source of some of my problems. I am using Flask on Windows 10.

I wish I knew how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Not familiar with Flask, but can you try removing BOM from file itself? https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+bom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

The string (BOM) is most likely included in your template file. Open/save it in some editor which doesn't include unnecessary symbols in UTF-8 files. For example Notepad++.

Comment: I found that when working in Visual Studio 2015, in a Python web project (using Flask or otherwise), if I select "HTML Page" from the "Add New Item" dialog then the newly added HTML file will be configured to save with the BOM. However, if I select "Text File" from the "Add New Item" dialog, but name it "page.html" (or whatever), it will save without the BOM.

Comment: If using Visual Studio and you need to fix files that already contain the BOM, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411486/4704976).