# Visual Studio 2019 react template create files with ISO 8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8

Tags: reactjs, npm, character-encoding, visual-studio-2019

I have a very strange issue I don't know how to solve. I created project from **react .net core mvc** template, but when I add characters like 'á,é,í,ó,ú' the Visual Studio save file as ISO 8859-1 (or the react files was already generated as that encoding) but instead of characters I can see question marks when I open the same file with Visual Studio Code as UTF-8. When I start debug, there are also question marks in the HTML. I can resave all the files with the Visual Studio code, but why the files are in ISO 8859-1?

First IDE is VS2019 and second one is Visual Studio Code

[image]

What settings I should check or adjust to have the files in UTF-8 instead of ISO 8859-1 when the project is creating (npm installing, etc)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to config visual studio to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for all projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335199/how-to-config-visual-studio-to-use-utf-8-as-the-default-encoding-for-all-project)

Comment: No, I have it unchecked, also I don't have issues with other projects, only this react one.

Comment: I can't test it on my end, though I suppose the template was made with `ISO 8859-1` and it's just duplicated from that source as-is on your computer. If it's a one time thing with this project, you could just convert all files to `UTF-8`

Comment: Thank you Emile, it is about several files, so it is not big deal, I was just surprised.