# Nuget server will corrupt my file's encodgin on local TFS

Tags: utf-8, tfs, nuget, local

when i push a package in nuget server (on a local TFS), it will corrupt file's encoding. of course if i open my index.cshtml in notepad it will show me utf-8 encoding but VS can't show unicode characters in run time and i have to open the cshtml file in notepad and saveAs it by utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that VS can not show the unicode characters correctly, but they can be showed correctly in VS after saving the file with utf-8 encoding?

In order to run UTF-8, you need a Byte Order Mark (BOM) sometimes called a signature. According to the description in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Unicode characters are now supported in identifiers, macros, string
> and character literals, and in comments. Universal character names are
> also now supported.
>
> Unicode can be input into a source code file in the following
> encodings:
>
> - UTF-16 little endian with or without byte order mark (BOM)
> - UTF-16 big endian with or without BOM
> - UTF-8 with BOM

For the love of all things decent, do NOT use "UTF-8 with BOM!"

You can try to recreate the nuget package in VS with the utf-8 encoding files, then publish it to the server, then try it again. While please note below things:

- Use the UTF-8 character encoding for the `*.nuspec`
- Do not save your *.nuspec files with a Byte Order Mark (BOM). A BOM
  is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, because it can lead to
  several issues.
- Specify the UTF-8 encoding in the first line of your `*.nuspec` files
  like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Also reference this thread: [UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: @Morteza Have you resolved your issue by above solution? any update?

Comment: VS can show mu uni-code characters in code editor but not in run time